# PHP prepare error

Tags: php, mysql, bit, prepare

I am well and truly stumped on this one. Here is a prepare bind command that I am using to activate a users account:

```
$query = "UPDATE `users` SET `active` = b'1' WHERE `UUID` = ?";
$stmt_update = $mysqli->prepare( $query );
$stmt_update->bind_param( 'i' , $uuid );
$stmt_update->execute();
```

So active is a bit(1) field in MySQL and UUID is the users Unique ID and when I run it I get the error:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object in /websites/.../activate.php on line 34
```

I do have another query that runs on the page and I do close it off with `$stmt->close;`

I tried a `var_dump($stmt_update);` which returns `bool(false)`

The query runs fine in PHPMyAdmin just not getting it's prepare set up =¬(

**UPDATE**

Switched the field to a boolean and changed my query to this:

```
$query = "UPDATE `users` SET `active` = 1 WHERE `UUID` = ?";
```

No avail as it is still not preparing the statement. Any more ideas?

Comment: No, it does not run fine in PHPMyAdmin. The SQL query certainly has a syntax error. Use mysqli_error() to find out.

Comment: yep. typo there: `= b'1'`

Comment: Just checked again in phpmyadmin and there's no syntax errors. what's the typo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right turns out I was missing () of my close command form the previous statement. I was using `$stmt->close;` not `$stmt->close();` It's always the smallest things....

Anyway I changed my field back to a bit and `active = b'1'` worked fine HUZZAR

Answer (score 1):

Your query is incorrect, and hence will not prepare correctly.

```
UPDATE `users` SET `active` = 1 WHERE `UUID` = ?
```

Would be the correct query (were you not using `BIT(1)`), and it's wise to move from a bit field with implicit boolean-ness to something more explicitly boolean: a boolean.

Tip: `ALTER TABLE users ALTER COLUMN active BOOL DEFAULT FALSE`
(`BOOL` is an alias of `tinyint(1)`. `TRUE`/`FALSE` are aliases of 1/0)

It is good practice to wrap your prepares as such, because prepare returns false on fail.

`false->method()` will always throw a fatal error.

```
if ($query = $db->prepare($sql)) {
    //work on query
} else {
    echo "Query prepare failed";
    echo $sql;
}
```

Comment: I should have said sorry but I have tried with both 1 and '1'. Please note that this is a bit field a well thus the b prefixing the number

Comment: Why isn't it a boolean? if you want true or false, make it true or false. Explicit is better than Implicit.

Comment: Tried the boolean method. still the same. I have updated the main post

Answer (score -2):

use

```
$query = "UPDATE `users` SET `active` = '1' WHERE `UUID` = :i";
```

Comment: This is using that PDO method right? Don't I need to declare the i somewhere?

Comment: you have it right here `$stmt_update->bind_param( 'i' , $uuid );`

Comment: You are confusing PDO with mysqli - the `bind_param()` takes value type and value as parameters the 'i' is for integer and $uuid is the value